# My Gridview adapter get random items with cursor

Tags: android, gridview, cursor, adapter

i'am trying to make one layout with GridView . So i make a simple Adapter with Cursors but he get random views on scrolling the GridView. I have read a lot of post but now one use CursorAdapter like me, or if the use like me they don't have my problem. I have tried to put ViewHolder, but still the same problem.

**Can anyone say me how can i make this work please?**

Here are some photo of what he make :
When get started

[photo1](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/850/7p68.png)

[image: photo1]

When get Scrolled

[photo2](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/853/qyhz.png)

[image: photo2]

The code i use
for set adapter :

```
cs = new CursorSongs();
aa = new AdapterAlbum(a,cs.getAllAlbums(a));
gvAlbums.setAdapter(aa);
gvAlbums.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

for adapter :

```
public class AdapterAlbum extends CursorAdapter{

public AdapterAlbum(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c,true);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    TextView tAlbum  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvAlbum);
    ImageView iAlbum = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iAlbum);

    tAlbum = holder.tAlbum;
    iAlbum = holder.iAlbum;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = i.inflate(R.layout.detalle_grid, parent,false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.tAlbum = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvAlbum);
    holder.iAlbum = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iAlbum);
    holder.tAlbum.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM)));
    String coverPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART));
    Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(coverPath);
    if(img != null){
        holder.iAlbum.setImageDrawable(img);
    }else{
        holder.iAlbum.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart_mp_unknown_list);
    }
    v.setTag(holder);

    return v;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView tAlbum;
    ImageView iAlbum;
}
```

Comment: the setText and setImageDrawable go into bindView, not in newView.

Comment: When i first created this Adapter i put that in bindView ,and still have the problem.

Comment: i don't know what you did before, but I can tell you the new view is only for inflating, and bindView is for putting stuff in the view.

Comment: i redited my code and my detail layout( i put text view with CompounDrawable) and seems like he problem is the loading of Bitmap and he's size . The bitmap from cursor seems to have many sizes , i guess that's the problem :S